# maven add new remote repository

Tags: java, maven

How can I add a new remote repository in the maven user settings config file? 
I added a new option for the one with the id "softwarementors", but when I run the update target on the maven project, it simply redirects to the configured nexus server nexus_server_ip_address.

How can I prevent this? How do I need to adjust the maven config file in order
to add a new remote repository. I replaced the nexus server's ip address with

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>nexus_server_ip_address/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>softwarementors</id>            <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/com/softwarementors/ex    tjs/directjngine/2.2/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Add this softwarementors at nexus

Comment: Is there another possible solution?

Comment: @patentul You could configure for which repositories your nexus is not the mirror (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

Comment: can you give me a specific example on how I do it in this case?

Comment: Is it just me, or is there a large space in your URL in the pom.xml ou posted?

Comment: Just ignore that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The mirrorOf pattern of * causes any repository request to be
>   redirected to this mirror and to your single repository group, which
>   in the example is the public group.

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

```
Solution 1 : add softwarementors to Nexus

Solution 2 :
            Add this.

                <mirror>
                  <id>softwarementors</id>
                  <mirrorOf>softwarementors</mirrorOf>
                  <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/com/softwarementors/extjs/directjngine/2.2/</url>
                </mirror> 

                <repository>
                    <id>softwarementors</id>
                    <name>softwarementors</name>        
                    <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/com/softwarementors/extjs/directjngine/2.2/</url>
                </repository>

Solution 3:

<mirror>
       <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
       <id>nexus</id>
       <mirrorOf>*,!softwarementors</mirrorOf>
       <url>nexus_server_ip_address/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

Comment: It does not work, it still redirects to the nexus server

Comment: solution 4 and clean => not use mirror and adds juste differents repositories because you mixte nexus + central +third party